# Hide rows based on cell value in an already filtered range

Tags: excel, vba, range, filtering

I have an Excel file that contains around 13k lines.

I hide some columns and then filter based on a few other columns. After this I have 100-150 lines left. So far my macro works.

The next step is to filter out the rows that have a value < 10 in column AH.

I could start with this as very first step, but it seems tedious to loop 13k lines when it is enough to loop 100-150 lines.

I tried two versions.

1. is stuck in a long loop, possibly because it is looping the 13k lines instead of the 100-150?

```vb
Dim LR As Long
Dim iCell As Range
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set iCell = Range("A2:BS" & LR).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
For Each iCell In Range("AH:AH").Cells
    If iCell.Value < 10 Then Rows(iCell.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next iCell
```

2. hides all rows left after my initial filtering

```vb
Dim cl As Range, rng As Range, LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A2:BS" & LR)
For Each cl In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If cl.Value < 10 Then Rows(cl.Row).EntireRow.Hidden = True
Next cl
```

How do I loop only the range of already filtered remaining 100-150 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```vb
    Dim cl As Range, LR As Long, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet ' or whatever
    LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each cl In ws.Range("AH2:AH" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If cl.Value < 10 Then cl.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next cl
```